# Best book to learn probability - Poisson, binomial, regression, etc

Tags: regression, probability, distributions, binomial-distribution, references

What is the best book to learn probability - Poisson, binomial, regression, etc.

I am working as an odds adjuster at a bookmaker and need to advance my skills to an odds compiler level.

Comment: Perhaps few here know what the mathematical level required of an odds adjuster is, or that of an odds compiler: it would probably help you to get better answers if you elaborated a little.

Comment: I understand. Hence, I stated poisson, binomial, etc. As these are what is required in the field. Most basic probability books cover these distributions at a very basic level. I am looking for, not an advanced but a complete book which would cover say "Poisson Regression" and not just "poisson" or "regression", separately. Again, appreciate all the help as at other forums I havent been getting many answers.

Comment: Saying 'Poisson' doesn't help all that much - Poisson processes are covered in graduate level monographs & in 'Statistics for Dummies'.

Comment: you are right. How about a probability book which will arm me with tools to deal with such a question "Wigan scores after 30 minutes. Calculate home, away and draw in percentage terms with poisson regression, assuming pre-match odds were 5.00 - 4.00 - 1.80 for Win/Draw/Loss respectively"

Answer (score 2):

Grinstead & Snell is very good (& free):

http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/book.html

(Note it doesn't cover statistical topics e.g. regression, just probability.)

As you mention Poisson regression in a comment:

[Dobson, *An Introduction to Generalized Models*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0CAgx5kQSwcC&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

Answer (score 0):

You could find some of the following of interest:

[Calculated-Bets-Computers-Gambling](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521009626)[1] and [Mathletics-Gamblers-Enthusiasts-Mathematics-Basketball](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691154589)[2]  books introducing probability directly in the gambling context.

The following might be too advanced for you, but maybe still useful:

[Anthology of Statistics in Sports](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898715873)[3] and [Statistical Reasoning in Sports](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1464114056)[4]

Comment: I added the post notice because this answer is unintelligible without following the links.  Please at least indicate what you are recommending. *Much* better would be to include the reasons for your recommendations.